# UITabBar icons are off-center on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbar

how do I ensure that my custom tab bar images are positioned in the centre of the UITabBarItems? 
here is my code:

```
[self.tab.tabBar.items[0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"homeIcon"]];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[0] setAccessibilityLabel:@"Home"];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchIcon"]];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[1] setAccessibilityLabel:@"Search"];

[self.tab.tabBar.items[2] setAccessibilityLabel:@"Add"];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[3] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"explore-standard"]];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[3] setAccessibilityLabel:@"Messages"];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[4] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile"]];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[4] setAccessibilityLabel:@"Profile"];

[self.tab.tabBar.items[0] setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home-thick"]];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[1] setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-thick"]];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[3] setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"explore-thick"]];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[4] setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-thick"]];

[self.tab.tabBar.items[0] setTitle:nil];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[1] setTitle:nil];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[2] setTitle:nil];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[3] setTitle:nil];
[self.tab.tabBar.items[4] setTitle:nil];
```

[image: tab bar]

Comment: Have you tried with the itemPositioning? Try this code in the viewDidLoad
`self.tab.tabBar.itemPositioning = UITabBarItemPositioningFill;`

Comment: yes, I've tried itemPositioningFill, UITabBarItemPositioningCentered and automatic, it has no effect on the result.

Comment: Try to add a different background color on all views so we can see who is moved.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it, instead of [self.tab.tabBar.items[0] setTitle:nil];  you need to put [self.tab.tabBar.items[0] setTitle:@""];

Comment: Your image probably has empty space padding. Inspect it in GIMP or something to check that it's trimmed properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting a `nil` title like this

```
[self.tab.tabBar.items[0] setTitle:nil];
```

results in an off-centre icon.

You need to set an empty string like so:

```
[self.tab.tabBar.items[0] setTitle:@""];
```

Comment: Thanks! This is also valid for Title set in Interface Builder. I fixed this by putting cursor in Title field and pressing Enter on keyboard